# this context in base constructor is module itself - Typescript

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

NOTE: changed title post-answer for better searchability as this had nothing to do with backbone.

```
 module App.BackBone.Collections {  
     export class MixedChartCollection extends Backbone.Collection {        
            public model: App.BackBone.Models.BaseChartModel;        
            constructor(models?: any, options?: any) {
                  super(models, options);
            }
       }
}
```

It seems the base Backbone.Collection constructor is called with `this` context being my module rather than my class o_O

Here is the constructor from backbone.js:

```
 var Collection = Backbone.Collection = function (models, options) {
      options || (options = {});
      if (options.url) this.url = options.url;
      if (options.model) this.model = options.model;
      if (options.comparator !== void 0) this.comparator = options.comparator;
      this._reset();  //ERROR: this._reset is not a function
      this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
      if (models) this.reset(models, _.extend({ silent: true }, options));
  };
```

In the image you can see how `App.BackBone.Collections` has the same 3 members (in red, with one of which is the class in question) as the `this` context and this._reset ends up being undefined because the what we really want it being "wrapped" my some object out of no where

Why is it doing this?

Here is compiled code for this class:

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    (function (BackBone) {
        (function (Collections) {
            var MixedChartCollection = (function (_super) {
                __extends(MixedChartCollection, _super);
                function MixedChartCollection(models, options) {
                    _super.call(this, models, options); //HERE "this" is not MixedChartCollection instance 
                }
                return MixedChartCollection;
            })(Backbone.Collection);
            Collections.MixedChartCollection = MixedChartCollection;            
        })(BackBone.Collections || (BackBone.Collections = {}));
        var Collections = BackBone.Collections;
    })(App.BackBone || (App.BackBone = {}));
    var BackBone = App.BackBone;
})(App || (App = {}));
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post the compiled code? It may be easier to help you (and I guess more people would look at it)

Comment: @Loamhoof Updated with compiled code. Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured this out.

It has to do with the way I instantiated the class:

```
 var mixedCollection: App.BackBone.Collections.MixedChartCollection
                        = App.BackBone.Collections.MixedChartCollection();
```

Just noticed I left out the "new" keyword which caused my issue.

Why did the compiler not catch this? I don't know. Not necessary but if somebody wants answer the reasoning behind that will mark as answer.

Comment: Actually, not putting the new keyword isn't an error in itself. It's just a whole different behavior: if you call a class without using the new keyword, the function will be run (in this case the initialize), but the "this" will be the object in which you made the call (and it won't create the object at the end). Also, when you create an item, you don't need the parenthesis if you don't pass any argument, that could prevent you from making this kind of mistake :)

Comment: thanks lot, i was also struggling with that 'new' keyword missed... :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume you have a BaseChartModel declared like this:

```
module App.Backbone.Models {
    export class BaseChartModel extends Backbone.Model {

    }
}
```

And your MixedChartCollection:

```
module App.Backbone.Collections {
    export class MixedChartCollection extends Backbone.Collection {
        public model: App.Backbone.Models.BaseChartModel;
        constructor(models?: any, options?: any) {
            super(models, options);
        }
    }
}
```

One key problem I see is the fact that you've got a namespace including `Backbone` and `Backbone`. As these translate to JavaScript:

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    (function (Backbone) {
        (function (Models) {
            var BaseChartModel = (function (_super) {
                __extends(BaseChartModel, _super);
                function BaseChartModel() {
                    _super.apply(this, arguments);

                }
                return BaseChartModel;
            })(Backbone.Model);
            Models.BaseChartModel = BaseChartModel;            
        })(Backbone.Models || (Backbone.Models = {}));
        var Models = Backbone.Models;
    })(App.Backbone || (App.Backbone = {}));
    var Backbone = App.Backbone; // << scope chain now includes Backbone
})(App || (App = {}));
var App;
(function (App) {
    (function (Backbone) {
        (function (Collections) {
            var MixedChartCollection = (function (_super) {
                __extends(MixedChartCollection, _super);
                function MixedChartCollection(models, options) {
                    _super.call(this, models, options);
                }
                return MixedChartCollection;
            })(App.Backbone.Collection);
            Collections.MixedChartCollection = MixedChartCollection;            
        })(Backbone.Collections || (Backbone.Collections = {}));
        var Collections = Backbone.Collections;
    })(App.Backbone || (App.Backbone = {}));
    var Backbone = App.Backbone;  // << scope chain now includes Backbone
})(App || (App = {}));
```

You'll find that you end up with a conflict where `Backbone` is set to `App.Backbone` (second to last line of the generated code).

```
var Backbone = App.Backbone; // << scope chain now includes Backbone
```

This completely changes the nature of the code as the inheritance now occurs for a locally scoped `Backbone` instance value rather than the BackboneJS `Model` class (same is true of the `Collection` class).

Try changing the module declaration to not use the Backbone namespace for your collection and model classes.

```
module App.My.Models {
    export class BaseChartModel extends Backbone.Model {

    }
}

module App.My.Collections {
    export class MixedChartCollection extends Backbone.Collection {
        public model: App.My.Models.BaseChartModel;
        constructor(models?: any, options?: any) {
            super(models, options);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you missed that my module naming is "BackBone" and backbone.js uses "Backbone" (capital letter difference) so there shouldn't be a problem there. I updated OP with compiled code from MixedChartCollection.